# Magento2 - multistore using different domains, relative folder in base url & store codes... language switcher broken

Tags: magento2.3, multistore, store-switcher, store-code

This is a **Magento 2.3.2 CE** project

Let's assume url of default storeview is https://www.domain.com/store/es

Url of second storeview is https://www.domain.pt/pt

Language switcher gives error, redirecting to same storeview 404 page... is this a bug or a feature? I understand this url configuration is weird, and it makes no sense using store codes in this case

Comment: Please check logs and provide more detail here.

Comment: I would be more worried about upgrading to the latest version than switching languages.

Comment: Hello @raul, Are you able to provide your root directory structure? I think you have created the wrong multi-store view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have also faced the similar issue last month and this is how i had fixed it.

try the below method hope this will work for you also

I managed to fix the problem by adding following code in `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIf Host [domain1] MAGE_RUN_CODE=[website1 code]
SetEnvIf Host [domain1] MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website 
SetEnvIf Host [domain2] MAGE_RUN_CODE=[website2 code] 
SetEnvIf Host [domain2] MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

let me know if this works for you

Comment: i have a wired issue, I can view my website by typing https://emerald.lk, but if i add www https://www.emerald.lk in front i am getting an error. Can you please help me to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, I had a similar issue and it was a result of having

`<referenceContainer name="content" display="false"/>`

in the custom layout update section of any category/CMS page. The reason for this is that Magento stores two key template files in the content referenceContainer to keep customer/store data up to date.