# Magento2 Requested store not found error while registration

Tags: magento2, stores, not-found

I am getting requested store not found error while registration
does anyone have idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by modifying `StoreManager.php` `(/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php)`

If `$storeId` is not defined: It retrieve data from COOKIE first, otherwise return the default store code.

**so what you need to do is just replace these lines of codes**

```
if (!isset($storeId) || '' === $storeId || $storeId === true) {
     if (null === $this->currentStoreId) {
\Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('store.resolve');
         $this->currentStoreId = $this->storeResolver->getCurrentStoreId();    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('store.resolve');
     }
     $storeId = $this->currentStoreId;
 }
```

**with this**

```
if(!$storeId) {
 if(isset($_COOKIE['store']) && $_COOKIE['store'] !== ''){
         $storeId = $_COOKIE['store'];
     } else {
         $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode();
     }           
 }
```

i hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks , it is working , but for my second website this code redirect to default website page

Comment: i think you need to customize store according to your requirements sir

Comment: refer my ans here may be this could be a help for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292933/magento2-multistore-using-different-domains-relative-folder-in-base-url-sto/296529#296529